# Close navigation container on click without hiding it

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, nav

So, I have a navigation bar and when the width is max 560px, hamburger menu appears for mobile devices.
What I am trying to do is when I click a :      li a href (ex.About) i want to close the nav-container, not to make it dissapear. Is there a way to do this?

Also I want this only to work for max-width 560px.

```css
/*--------------------------------
FONTS
---------------------------------*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');

/*--------------------------------
RESET
---------------------------------*/
* {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*--------------------------------
GLOBAL
---------------------------------*/
p {
  color: #767676;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #daa37f;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #a37a60;
}

.btn--opacity {
  animation: opacity 3s;
}

/*--------------------------------
NAVIGATION BAR
---------------------------------*/
nav {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgb(108, 108, 108);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(108, 108, 108, 1) 0%, rgba(78, 78, 78, 1) 35%, rgba(73, 73, 73, 1) 78%, rgba(29, 29, 29, 1) 100%);
  height: 60px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #d7a256;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  .nav-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #1f2227;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }

  .nav-container ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
  }

  .nav-container ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .nav-container ul li:nth-child(1) a {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }

  .nav-container ul li:nth-child(2) a {
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
  }

  .nav-container ul li:nth-child(3) a {
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
  }

  .nav-container ul li:nth-child(4) a {
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
  }

  .nav-container ul li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .nav-container ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }

  .nav-open {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .nav-open i {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-left: 14px;
  }

  .nav-open i:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }

  .nav-open i:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 4px;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .nav-open i:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open i {
  background: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open i:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(180deg);
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open i:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open i:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(90deg);
}

#nav:checked~.nav-container {
  z-index: 9990;
  opacity: 1;
}

#nav:checked~.nav-container ul li a {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.mt-5, .my-5 {
  margin-top: 0rem !important;
}

/*--------------------------------
BANNER
---------------------------------*/
.banner {
  background-image: url('../img/banner.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 93%;
  position: relative;
}

.banner_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner_container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.banner_scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: MoveUpDown 1s linear infinite;
}


/*--------------------------------
BANNER ANIMATION
---------------------------------*/
@keyframes MoveUpDown {
  0%, 100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }

  50% {
    bottom: 10px;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both
}

.animatedFadeInUp {
    opacity: 0
}

.fadeInUp {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
}


/*--------------------------------
Carpusel Gallery
---------------------------------*/

.w-100 {
  object-fit: cover;
}

/*--------------------------------
MENU SECTION
---------------------------------*/
#menu {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu_title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 800;
  opacity: 50%;
  color: #dfaf6b;
}

.menu_titleb {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 65px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #dfaf6b;
}

/*--------------------------------
Image Menu Lightbox
---------------------------------*/
a.lightbox img {
  position: fixed;
  scroll-behavior: none;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  margin: 94px 20px 20px 20px;
}

/* Styles the lightbox, removes it from sight and adds the fade-in transition */
.lightbox-target {
  z-index: 16;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Styles the lightbox image, centers it vertically and horizontally, adds the zoom-in transition and makes it responsive using a combination of margin and absolute positioning */
.lightbox-target img {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 0%;
  max-width: 0%;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Styles the close link, adds the slide down transition */
a.lightbox-close {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */
a.lightbox-close:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 26px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */
a.lightbox-close:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 26px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Uses the :target pseudo-class to perform the animations upon clicking the .lightbox-target anchor */
.lightbox-target:target {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.lightbox-target:target img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.lightbox-target:target a.lightbox-close {
  top: 0px;
}

/*--------------------------------
MENU SECTION IMAGE GRID
---------------------------------*/
.container {
  padding: 5rem 0rem;
}

.img-wrapper-20 {
  margin: 0rem 1.5rem 0rem 0rem;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.img-wrapper-20 img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.img-dimension {
    max-width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .d-flex {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .img-wrapper-20 {
        max-width: 80%;
        margin: 0rem 1.5rem 0rem 0rem;
    }
}


.galp {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
}

.buttonn {
  text-align: center;
}

/*--------------------------------
Footer
---------------------------------*/
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.footer-section {
  background-image: url('../img/banner-down.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-cta {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #373636;
}

.single-cta i {
  color: #d4a253;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.cta-text {
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cta-text h4 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.cta-text h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;

}

.cta-text span {
  color:#f4dcb6;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.footer-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.footer-pattern img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 330px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}

.footer-logo {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.footer-logo img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.footer-text p {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#f4dcb6;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.footer-social-icon span {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-social-icon a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.footer-social-icon i {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.facebook-bg {
  background: #3B5998;
}

.instagram-bg {
  background: #9254a9;
}

.footer-widget-heading h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-widget-heading h3::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ff5e14;
}

.footer-widget ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.footer-widget ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff5e14;
}

.footer-widget ul li a {
  color: #878787;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.subscribe-form {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subscribe-form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  border: 1px solid #2E2E2E;
  color: #fff;
}

.subscribe-form button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: #ff5e14;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff5e14;
  top: 0;
}

.subscribe-form button i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  transform: rotate(-6deg);
}


.align-items-center {
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}
.d-flex {
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}
.buttonn {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

    .buttonn {
      margin-bottom: 80px;
      margin-right: 22px;
    }
}

.map-container-3{
overflow: auto;
padding-bottom:16.25%;
position:relative;
height:30%;
}
.map-container-3 iframe{
left:0;
top:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden" />
      <label for="nav" class="nav-open"><i></i><i></i><i></i></label>
      <div class="nav-container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home" style="color:#d7a256">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#footer">Find us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will work for max-width 560px as it is showing only for that screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
ul.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const data = document.getElementById('nav');
  data.checked = false
})
```

```css
/*--------------------------------
FONTS
---------------------------------*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');

/*--------------------------------
RESET
---------------------------------*/

* {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/*--------------------------------
GLOBAL
---------------------------------*/

p {
  color: #767676;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #daa37f;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #a37a60;
}

.btn--opacity {
  animation: opacity 3s;
}


/*--------------------------------
NAVIGATION BAR
---------------------------------*/

nav {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgb(108, 108, 108);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(108, 108, 108, 1) 0%, rgba(78, 78, 78, 1) 35%, rgba(73, 73, 73, 1) 78%, rgba(29, 29, 29, 1) 100%);
  height: 60px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #d7a256;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  .nav-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #1f2227;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }
  .nav-container ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-container ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-container ul li:nth-child(1) a {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }
  .nav-container ul li:nth-child(2) a {
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
  }
  .nav-container ul li:nth-child(3) a {
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
  }
  .nav-container ul li:nth-child(4) a {
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
  }
  .nav-container ul li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .nav-container ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }
  .nav-open {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .nav-open i {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-left: 14px;
  }
  .nav-open i:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  .nav-open i:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 4px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav-open i:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open i {
  background: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open i:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(180deg);
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open i:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav:checked+.nav-open i:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(90deg);
}

#nav:checked~.nav-container {
  z-index: 9990;
  opacity: 1;
}

#nav:checked~.nav-container ul li a {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.mt-5,
.my-5 {
  margin-top: 0rem !important;
}


/*--------------------------------
BANNER
---------------------------------*/

.banner {
  background-image: url('../img/banner.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 93%;
  position: relative;
}

.banner_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner_container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.banner_scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: MoveUpDown 1s linear infinite;
}


/*--------------------------------
BANNER ANIMATION
---------------------------------*/

@keyframes MoveUpDown {
  0%,
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 10px;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0)
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0)
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both
}

.animatedFadeInUp {
  opacity: 0
}

.fadeInUp {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
}


/*--------------------------------
Carpusel Gallery
---------------------------------*/

.w-100 {
  object-fit: cover;
}


/*--------------------------------
MENU SECTION
---------------------------------*/

#menu {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu_title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 800;
  opacity: 50%;
  color: #dfaf6b;
}

.menu_titleb {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 65px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #dfaf6b;
}


/*--------------------------------
Image Menu Lightbox
---------------------------------*/

a.lightbox img {
  position: fixed;
  scroll-behavior: none;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  margin: 94px 20px 20px 20px;
}


/* Styles the lightbox, removes it from sight and adds the fade-in transition */

.lightbox-target {
  z-index: 16;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Styles the lightbox image, centers it vertically and horizontally, adds the zoom-in transition and makes it responsive using a combination of margin and absolute positioning */

.lightbox-target img {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 0%;
  max-width: 0%;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}


/* Styles the close link, adds the slide down transition */

a.lightbox-close {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}


/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */

a.lightbox-close:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 26px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}


/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */

a.lightbox-close:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 26px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


/* Uses the :target pseudo-class to perform the animations upon clicking the .lightbox-target anchor */

.lightbox-target:target {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.lightbox-target:target img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.lightbox-target:target a.lightbox-close {
  top: 0px;
}


/*--------------------------------
MENU SECTION IMAGE GRID
---------------------------------*/

.container {
  padding: 5rem 0rem;
}

.img-wrapper-20 {
  margin: 0rem 1.5rem 0rem 0rem;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.img-wrapper-20 img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.img-dimension {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .d-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .img-wrapper-20 {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0rem 1.5rem 0rem 0rem;
  }
}

.galp {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
}

.buttonn {
  text-align: center;
}


/*--------------------------------
Footer
---------------------------------*/

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.footer-section {
  background-image: url('../img/banner-down.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-cta {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #373636;
}

.single-cta i {
  color: #d4a253;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.cta-text {
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cta-text h4 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.cta-text h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.cta-text span {
  color: #f4dcb6;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.footer-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.footer-pattern img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 330px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}

.footer-logo {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.footer-logo img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.footer-text p {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #f4dcb6;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.footer-social-icon span {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-social-icon a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.footer-social-icon i {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.facebook-bg {
  background: #3B5998;
}

.instagram-bg {
  background: #9254a9;
}

.footer-widget-heading h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-widget-heading h3::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ff5e14;
}

.footer-widget ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.footer-widget ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff5e14;
}

.footer-widget ul li a {
  color: #878787;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.subscribe-form {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subscribe-form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  border: 1px solid #2E2E2E;
  color: #fff;
}

.subscribe-form button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: #ff5e14;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff5e14;
  top: 0;
}

.subscribe-form button i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  transform: rotate(-6deg);
}

.align-items-center {
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}

.d-flex {
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}

.buttonn {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .buttonn {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    margin-right: 22px;
  }
}

.map-container-3 {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 16.25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 30%;
}

.map-container-3 iframe {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden" />
    <label for="nav" class="nav-open"><i></i><i></i><i></i></label>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" style="color:#d7a256">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#footer">Find us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```